# please regex url request

Tags: regex, url, justin.tv

I would like to know if anybody can help me with a regular expression problem.  I want to write a regular expression to catch URLs similar to this URL:

```
www.justin.tv/channel_name_here
```

I have tried:

```
/justin\.tv\/(.*)
```

The problem I get is that when this channel goes live, sometimes the URL transforms to something like this:

```
www.justin.tv/channel_name_here#/w/45365675688
```

I can't catch this. :(  Can anybody please help me with this?  I just want to catch the channel name without the pound symbol and the rest of the URL.

Here are some example URLs:

```
www.justin.tv/winning_movies#/w/6347562128
http://www.justin.tv/cine_accion_hd16#/w/6347562128/18
http://www.justin.tv/fox_movies_hd1/
```

I would want to get:

```
winning_movies
cine_accion_hd16
fox_movies_hd1
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:

```
(?<=justin\.tv\/)([^#\/]+)
```

Long answer:

Let's split this up into parts.  Look at the back part first.

```
([^#\/]+)
```

This delimits the string into parts that don't include either '#' or '/'.
Now let's look at the first part.

```
(?<=justin\.tv\/)
```

The syntax "(?<=" followed by ")" is called positive lookbehind ([this page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) has good examples and explanation of the different types of lookaround).  Using a simple example:

```
(?<=A)B
```

The above example says "I want all 'B' that are immediately after an 'A'."  Going to our big example, we're saying we want all parts (separated by '#' or '/') that are *immediately after* a part called "justin.tv/".

Look [here](http://rubular.com/r/mZfEKLM1hI) for an example of the expression in action.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH, That was what I was looking for, thank's too for the explain  the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
@justin\.tv/([^#/]+)@
```

If you want everything up to a certain character(-set), use a negated class.
Also, when working on regex for urls, using / as delimiter is error-prone, as you have to escape all the /'s. Use something else instead (like @ in this case)